# Question about continuity of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, normed-spaces

> Assume $ W,V $ are two normed vector spaces over $ \mathbb{C} $ and let $ T:V\to W $ be a linear transformation.
>
> Prove that $ T $ is continuous if and only if for any sequence of vectors $ (v_n)_n $ such that $v_n \to \vec{0}$, we have
> $$ \sup_{n}\|Tv_{n}\|<\infty $$

The first direction is easy, if $T$ is continuous then for any sequence of vectors that converges to $\vec{0}$ we have
$$
\lim_{n}\|Tv_{n}\|
 =\|T(0)\|
 = 0
$$
and thus the sequence $\|Tv_{n}\|$ converges and also bounded.

I'm struggling with the other direction. Say for any sequence of vectors that converges to $\vec{0}$ we have that $\sup_{n} \|Tv_{n}\|<\infty$. How can I use that to prove that $T$ is continuous in $0$ ? (This would imply that $T$ is continuous in the whole space).

Alternatively, if I'll find a way to show that the given detail implies that $\|T\|<\infty$, this would also be enough to conclude that $T$ is continuous.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ is discontinuous at some $x_0\in X$. Then, since $T$ is linear, it is also discontinuous at $0$. So, there's some sequence $(v_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n=0$ and that you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tv_n=0$. So, for some $\varepsilon>0$, there are infinitely many $n$'s such that $\|Tv_n\|\geqslant\varepsilon$. You can assume without loss of generality that this occurs for every $n$. But then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\|v_n\|}}=0$ too, $$\left\|T\frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\|v_n\|}}\right\|\geqslant\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt{\|v_n\|}}$$and, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\|v_n\|}=0$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|T\frac{v_n}{\sqrt{\|v_n\|}}\right\|=\infty.$$